# Convert list of ints to one number?

Tags: python

I have a list of integers that I would like to convert to one number like:

```
numList = [1, 2, 3]
num = magic(numList)

print num, type(num)
>>> 123, <type 'int'>
```

What is the best way to implement the *magic* function?

**EDIT** 
I did find [this](http://bytes.com/groups/python/722951-int-str-list-elements), but it seems like there has to be a better way.

Comment: It appears that you're assuming base 10. True?

Comment: `int(''.join([str(n) for n in numList]))`

Answer (score 184, accepted):

```
# Over-explaining a bit:
def magic(numList):         # [1,2,3]
    s = map(str, numList)   # ['1','2','3']
    s = ''.join(s)          # '123'
    s = int(s)              # 123
    return s


# How I'd probably write it:
def magic(numList):
    s = ''.join(map(str, numList))
    return int(s)


# As a one-liner  
num = int(''.join(map(str,numList)))


# Functionally:
s = reduce(lambda x,y: x+str(y), numList, '')
num = int(s)


# Using some oft-forgotten built-ins:
s = filter(str.isdigit, repr(numList))
num = int(s)
```

Comment: I had thought the map function was deprecated in favor of list comprehensions, but now I can no longer find a note to that effect.  thank you, I'll be adding that back into my vocabulary.

Comment: I assume there's a bug in your "# How I'd probably write it:" and it should be `''.join(map(str, numList))` ?  Also, for your "Cleverly" option, you need to int() the result.

Comment: Yes your missing map in #2. for a moment there I thought you really were doing magic!

Comment: TokenMacGuy: you mean this? - http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196 map, reduce, filter, lambda were all to go in 3k originally

Comment: +1 for the first two methods, the "functional" way seems a bit silly, and the filter/str.isdigit way seems like a horrible hack

Comment: Small improvement to the functional method:
reduce(lambda x,y: 10*x+y, numList)

Comment: @DaveRadcliffe: for small len(numList), [`reduce(lambda n,d:10*n+d,..` is even faster than 'int(''.join(map(..`](https://gist.github.com/zed/ac0f5df365dffdb94f97476a89d38c8f#file-summary-org)

Comment: functionally => `s = reduce(lambda x,y: x*10+y, numList, 0)`

Answer (score 56):

Two solutions:

```
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3]
>>> magic = lambda nums: int(''.join(str(i) for i in nums)) # Generator exp.
>>> magic(nums)
123
>>> magic = lambda nums: sum(digit * 10 ** (len(nums) - 1 - i) # Summation
...     for i, digit in enumerate(nums))
>>> magic(nums)
123
```

The `map`-oriented solution actually comes out ahead on my box -- you definitely should not use `sum` for things that might be large numbers:

[image: Timeit Comparison]

```
import collections
import random
import timeit

import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

MICROSECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1E6
FUNS = []
def test_fun(fun):
    FUNS.append(fun)
    return fun

@test_fun
def with_map(nums):
    return int(''.join(map(str, nums)))

@test_fun
def with_interpolation(nums):
    return int(''.join('%d' % num for num in nums))

@test_fun
def with_genexp(nums):
    return int(''.join(str(num) for num in nums))

@test_fun
def with_sum(nums):
    return sum(digit * 10 ** (len(nums) - 1 - i)
        for i, digit in enumerate(nums))

@test_fun
def with_reduce(nums):
    return int(reduce(lambda x, y: x + str(y), nums, ''))

@test_fun
def with_builtins(nums):
    return int(filter(str.isdigit, repr(nums)))

@test_fun
def with_accumulator(nums):
    tot = 0
    for num in nums:
        tot *= 10
        tot += num
    return tot

def time_test(digit_count, test_count=10000):
    """
    :return: Map from func name to (normalized) microseconds per pass.
    """
    print 'Digit count:', digit_count
    nums = [random.randrange(1, 10) for i in xrange(digit_count)]
    stmt = 'to_int(%r)' % nums
    result_by_method = {}
    for fun in FUNS:
        setup = 'from %s import %s as to_int' % (__name__, fun.func_name)
        t = timeit.Timer(stmt, setup)
        per_pass = t.timeit(number=test_count) / test_count
        per_pass *= MICROSECONDS_PER_SECOND
        print '%20s: %.2f usec/pass' % (fun.func_name, per_pass)
        result_by_method[fun.func_name] = per_pass
    return result_by_method

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass_times_by_method = collections.defaultdict(list)
    assert_results = [fun([1, 2, 3]) for fun in FUNS]
    assert all(result == 123 for result in assert_results)
    digit_counts = range(1, 100, 2)
    for digit_count in digit_counts:
        for method, result in time_test(digit_count).iteritems():
            pass_times_by_method[method].append(result)
    for method, pass_times in pass_times_by_method.iteritems():
        pyplot.plot(digit_counts, pass_times, label=method)
    pyplot.legend(loc='upper left')
    pyplot.xlabel('Number of Digits')
    pyplot.ylabel('Microseconds')
    pyplot.show()
```

Comment: No problem, but remember you should probably use what's most readable unless you find it's a bottleneck. I just like timing things. ;-)

Comment: I've measured performance of the above function. The results are slightly different e.g. with_accumulator() is faster for small `digit_count`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489999/python-convert-list-of-ints-to-one-number/493944#493944

Comment: I can confirm that `with_accumulator` looks better on my machine M1 + python3

Answer (score 11):

```
def magic(number):
    return int(''.join(str(i) for i in number))
```

Comment: Nitpick - you can remove the `[ ]` and do the str'ing as a generation expression. `int(''.join(str(i) for i in number))` - it's.. two bytes quicker!

Answer (score 7):

Just for completeness, here's a variant that uses `print()` (works on Python 2.6-3.x):

```
from __future__ import print_function
try: from cStringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
     from io import StringIO

def to_int(nums, _s = StringIO()):
    print(*nums, sep='', end='', file=_s)
    s = _s.getvalue()
    _s.truncate(0)
    return int(s)
```

### Time performance of different solutions

I've measured performance of [@cdleary's functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489999/python-convert-list-of-ints-to-one-number#490031). The results are slightly different.

Each function tested with the input list generated by:

```
def randrange1_10(digit_count): # same as @cdleary
    return [random.randrange(1, 10) for i in xrange(digit_count)]
```

You may supply your own function via `--sequence-creator=yourmodule.yourfunction` command-line argument (see below).

The fastest functions for a given number of integers in a list (`len(nums) == digit_count`) are:

- `len(nums)` in **1..30**

  ```
  def _accumulator(nums):
      tot = 0
      for num in nums:
          tot *= 10
          tot += num
      return tot
  ```
- `len(nums)` in **30..1000**

  ```
  def _map(nums):
      return int(''.join(map(str, nums)))

  def _imap(nums):
      return int(''.join(imap(str, nums)))
  ```

[image: Figure: N = 1000]

```
|------------------------------+-------------------|
| Fitting polynom              | Function          |
|------------------------------+-------------------|
| 1.00  log2(N)   +  1.25e-015 | N                 |
| 2.00  log2(N)   +  5.31e-018 | N*N               |
| 1.19  log2(N)   +      1.116 | N*log2(N)         |
| 1.37  log2(N)   +      2.232 | N*log2(N)*log2(N) |
|------------------------------+-------------------|
| 1.21  log2(N)   +      0.063 | _interpolation    |
| 1.24  log2(N)   -      0.610 | _genexp           |
| 1.25  log2(N)   -      0.968 | _imap             |
| 1.30  log2(N)   -      1.917 | _map              |
```

[image: Figure: N = 1000_000]

To plot the first figure download [`cdleary.py` and `make-figures.py`](http://gist.github.com/51074) and run (`numpy` and `matplotlib` must be installed to plot):

```
$ python cdleary.py
```

Or

```
$ python make-figures.py --sort-function=cdleary._map \
> --sort-function=cdleary._imap \
> --sort-function=cdleary._interpolation \
> --sort-function=cdleary._genexp --sort-function=cdleary._sum \
> --sort-function=cdleary._reduce --sort-function=cdleary._builtins \
> --sort-function=cdleary._accumulator \
> --sequence-creator=cdleary.randrange1_10 --maxn=1000
```

Comment: That's a strange way to write it in a Python 2.6/3.0 way.. `print(''.join(str(x) for x in [1,2,3,4,5]))` will work in Python 2.5, 2.6, 3.x, probably more...

Comment: @dbr: the purpose was to use the print function. It is not recommended way, that's why I wrote "for completeness".

Answer (score 6):

```
def magic(numbers):
    return int(''.join([ "%d"%x for x in numbers]))
```

Answer (score 4):

pseudo-code:

```
int magic(list nums)
{
  int tot = 0

  while (!nums.isEmpty())
  {
    int digit = nums.takeFirst()
    tot *= 10
    tot += digit
  }

  return tot
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the part where he was looking for a python solution :P

Comment: That's okay -- Andrew's solution was actually one of the fastest when converted to Python. +1 from me!

Comment: It is the fastest solution (@cdleary's implementation in Python) if the list size is less than 30. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489999/python-convert-list-of-ints-to-one-number/493944#493944

Answer (score 4):

A one-liner without needing to cast to and from `str`

```
def magic(num):
    return sum(e * 10**i for i, e in enumerate(num[::-1]))
```

Answer (score 4):

if the list contains only integer:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x*10+y, list)
```

Comment: It may not be obvious to the casual observer, so a warning: this only works with base 10. This also does not appear to work if the items in the list are greater than 9. For example, [1, 250] should equal 1250, but the answer is 260. This answer works as expected: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37451273/1030576

Answer (score 3):

This method works in 2.x as long as each element in the list is only a single digit.  But you shouldn't actually use this.  It's horrible.

```
>>> magic = lambda l:int(`l`[1::3])
>>> magic([3,1,3,3,7])
31337
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a generator expression:

```
def magic(numbers):
    digits = ''.join(str(n) for n in numbers)
    return int(digits)
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems pretty clean, to me.

```
def magic( aList, base=10 ):
    n= 0
    for d in aList:
        n = base*n + d
    return n
```

Comment: `reduce(lambda x, y: base*x + y, aList, 0)` is even cleaner ;)

Comment: @Xion: "cleaner"?  Not to some folks.  `reduce()` often creates additional problems when used carelessly.  I strongly encourage your to post your own answer, since yours is so different from this one.

Comment: This does not appear to work. [1, 249] as a base 16 number should equal 505 (256 + 249), but this expression yields a result of 265.

Answer (score 2):

I found some examples are not compatible with python 3 I test one from @Triptych

`s = filter(str.isdigit, repr(numList))`
`num = int(s)`

in python 3 it's gonna give error

`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'filter'`

i think the more simple and compatible way would be

```
def magic(num_list):
    return int("".join(map(str, num_list)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful

```
def digits_to_number(digits):
    return reduce(lambda x,y : x+y, map(str,digits))

print digits_to_number([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using numpy (with `import numpy as np`):

```
In [24]: x
Out[24]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [25]: np.dot(x, 10**np.arange(len(x)-1, -1, -1))
Out[25]: 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this seems to be the simplest solution **with no need for any fcn**

```py
res = int(''.join(numList))
```

NOTE: This implementation is in Python 3

Comment: Don't the elements have to be of type strings for this to work?

Comment: The elements in the list are integers, join() will work only on string elements

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread while trying to convert a list to the real value of the underlying int in terms of a C-style pointer, but none of the other answers appear to work for this case. I think the following solution works as intended and could be useful to others even though it doesn't necessarily answer the original question.

```
def listToInt(x, reverseBytes=False):
  if reverseBytes:
    x = x[::-1]
  return reduce(lambda x,y: x*256+y, x)
```

`listToInt([1, 249]) == 505`

`listToInt([249, 1], True) == 505`

The primary value of this is to emulate the behavior of casting a byte array to another data type, e.g. uint16, which Python can't seem to do natively, on either a big or little endian system.

Answer (score 0):

Too late for the party here is the approch without converting to string

```py
x=0
k=len(a)-1
for i in a:
    x+=(10**k)*i
    k-=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one-line formula can be useful too:

```
s=sum([numlist[i] * 10**(len(numlist)-i-1) for i in range(len(numlist))])
```

Answer (score 0):

A pair of non-`str`s based approaches.

**Assumed** that each term in `numList` is a natural number smaller than 10.

With `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

numList = [1, 2, 3, 4]

tot = reduce(lambda i, j: i+j[1]*10**(len(numList)-j[0]-1), enumerate(numList), 0)
```

---

Used `zip`/`map` to couple coefficients with the powers of the base.

The `zip`-way:

```
numList = [1, 2, 3]
tot = sum(coef*10**i for coef, i in zip(numList, range(len(numList)-1, -1, -1)))
print(tot)
```

The `map`-way:

```
numList = [1, 2, 3]

base_pows = map(int(10).__pow__, range(len(numList)-1, -1, -1))
tot = sum(map(int.__mul__, numList, base_pows))
print(tot)
```