# Join integers in a list of lists in python

Tags: python

This is the closest I could come up with: [Convert list of ints to one number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489999/convert-list-of-ints-to-one-number)

Basically, I have an list of lists of integers:

```
arr = [[2,3,4], [1,2,3], [3,4,5]]
```

How do I get this so that it's: [234, 123, 345] as integers?

Edit: I would like to vectorize this code that I can use:

```
result = np.zeros(len(arr))
for i in range(len(arr)):
    result[i] = int(''.join(map(str, arr[i])))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[int(''.join(map(str, x))) for x in arr]
# [234, 123, 345]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it!

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [[2,3,4], [1,2,3], [3,4,5]]
arr2 = []
for x in arr:
    z = ""
    for y in x:
        z = z + str(y)
    arr2.append(int(z))
#the results are now in arr2
print arr2
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more mathematical way:

```
>>> [sum(n*10**i for i, n in enumerate(reversed(x))) for x in arr]
[234, 123, 345]
```