# Running through combinations of 4 numbers

Tags: python, combinations

I need a code that would run through the possible combinations of 4 numbers e.g 1234 would produce 24 combinations of 1234, 1243, 1324 ... ect ect. But does not do ['1', '12', '123', ect] I want it to be only 4 number length combinations, (just changing the order)

A long option would be to

```
    import random
```

randomise one of the 4 numbers, randomise another and another and another, check if that combination had been printed or like added to an array that held the possible combinations and then eventually printed out all of them.

```
array = ['1234', '1243', '1342', '1324' ect]
```

That would take long though and is highly inefficient. 
Pretty new to coding :)
Thanks

Comment: maybe this question could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements

Comment: @boroboris I don't want it to be '1' '12' '123' which would produce more than 24 combinations. Will add this to the description. Thank you for the suggestion though

Comment: @Mormin Hi Im pretty new to this. Can you explain what is wrong with my question? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution using [***itertools.permutations()***](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.permutations) and [***str.join()***](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) functions:

```
import itertools

n = '1234'
a = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.permutations(n, 4)]

print(a)   # prints 24 permutations
```

The output:

```
['1234', '1243', '1324', '1342', '1423', '1432', '2134', '2143', '2314', '2341', '2413', '2431', '3124', '3142', '3214', '3241', '3412', '3421', '4123', '4132', '4213', '4231', '4312', '4321']
```

Comment: Your `list` call here doesn't add anything.

Comment: @DSM, right, No reason for `list` call, it was for debug at start(before join). Fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin module `itertools` in python. Refer to this question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

```
import itertools
array = itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3, 4])

for eachpermutation in array:
    print(eachpermutation )
```

Should give you the output such as this

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 4, 3)
(1, 3, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 4, 2)
(1, 4, 2, 3)
(1, 4, 3, 2)
(2, 1, 3, 4)
(2, 1, 4, 3)
(2, 3, 1, 4)
(2, 3, 4, 1)
(2, 4, 1, 3)
(2, 4, 3, 1)
(3, 1, 2, 4)
(3, 1, 4, 2)
(3, 2, 1, 4)
(3, 2, 4, 1)
(3, 4, 1, 2)
(3, 4, 2, 1)
(4, 1, 2, 3)
(4, 1, 3, 2)
(4, 2, 1, 3)
(4, 2, 3, 1)
(4, 3, 1, 2)
(4, 3, 2, 1)
```

If you need to concatenate the sublists into a single number, you can use the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489999/convert-list-of-ints-to-one-number)

```
for eachpermutation in array:
    print(int(''.join(str(i) for i in eachpermutation )))
```

gives you the following output

```
1234
1243
1324
1342
1423
1432
2134
2143
2314
2341
2413
2431
3124
3142
3214
3241
3412
3421
4123
4132
4213
4231
4312
4321
```

Hope that helps