# Use python's reduce method to unpack list of integers

Tags: python

I am teaching myself python. I need to understand how the reduce function works. I have a solid understanding of how to use reduce for mathematical functions. However, I am trying to perform a more abstract operation to a list of integers and I encountered a problem.

**Problem**: I would like to take list like

```
digits= [3,4,3,2,1]
```

and unpack them such that I get

```
34421
```

**Approach** : I really cannot figure out how to create a lambda function that will extract the integer from the list. My approach is very bad and it is because I don't understand how to apply the function to the list. Also, I should note I am **using python 3**.

**Example Code**:

```
from functools import reduce
digits= [3,4,3,2,1]

reduce(lambda x : x, digits)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/280242/2681632.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489999/convert-list-of-ints-to-one-number

Comment: `reduce(lambda x, y: 10*x + y, digits)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> digits= [3,4,3,2,1]
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:10*x+y,digits)
34321
```

Edit: Now the script returns an integer, credit to schwobaseggl.

Comment: That is close to what I was trying to do, but I need to get an exact integer string. This is the dilemma. If this was c++ then it would be fairly trivial, but I would to implement this method in python

Comment: @EvanGertis Edited, now the code will return an integer