# Is there a way to exclude a specific integer from being randomly generated?

Tags: python, random

I'm attempting a problem which asks me to define a func() that generates 4 unique random integers from 2-8 (inclusive). I've got everything working so far, except that I can't figure out if it's even possible to ensure that the next randomly generated integer isn't a repeat from the given range (2-8)

Code so far:

```
def get_unique_code():
    code_str = ""

    while len(code_str) != 4:
        x = str(random.randint(2,8))
        code_str += x
    return code_str
```

Expected output:
6842

Got:
6846

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a list of random numbers, map to string and join them together.
Don't forget to add +1 to your upper bound to make it inclusive.

```py
import random


def get_unique_code():
    return ''.join(map(str, random.sample(range(2, 8 + 1), 4)))


print(get_unique_code())
```

See:

- [How do I create a list of random numbers without duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9755538/15497888)
- [Convert list of ints to one number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/489999/15497888)

Answer (score 1):

We can check if the character is already in the string:

```
def get_unique_code():
    code_str = ""

    while len(code_str) != 4:
        cont = False
        while not cont:
            x = str(random.randint(2,8))
            if x not in code_str:
                cont=True
        code_str += x
    return code_str
```